# Problems deleting MySQL row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP and mySQL, and so I'm really confused as to why this isn't working:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$response["id"] = $row["id"];
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$response['id']'");
$response["name"] = $row["name"];
$response["message"] = $row["message"];
$response["city"] = $row["city"];
$response["time"] = $row["date"];

$response["success"] = 1;
```

I basically want to delete the row right away.  I've tried a ton of different things, and I think my syntax must be wrong somewhere.  I tried saying

```
$todelete = $response["id"];
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$todelete'");
```

But no good.  What's odd is if I say

```
 mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID=4");
```

it deletes the row with the ID of 4 just fine.

I'm sure this is a really dumb mistake, can someone educate me?

Comment: First try to echo the sql string and see if it have id.

Comment: **[Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) can help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$todelete'");
```

change this line to

```
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='".$todelete."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a string formatting issue. Here are some options:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID = '{$row['id']}'");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID = '" . $row['id'] . "'");

// Or try this

$todelete = $row["id"];

mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID = '$todelete'");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID = '" . $todelete . "'");
```

**Make sure your code is not susceptible to SQL Injection!**

Comment: None of these worked :(  I think it must be due to the type of $response['id'].  For instance, saying $id = 7 and then doing a DELETE WHERE id=$id works just fine.  But saying $id = $response['id'] is no good.

Comment: @user1903064 - You placed the string within `mysql_query()`?

Comment: @user1903064 - Updated answer to use `$row['id']`.

Comment: I'm at a loss.  I don't want to waste any more of your time, since this is such an odd issue that perhaps something else is going wrong beyond my knowledge... but I fail to understand why $id = 8, "DELETE FROM balloons WHERE id=$id" works, whereas $id=$row['id'] "DELETE FROM balloons WHERE id=$id" doesn't work.  I've even tried casting $id as an int...  This is so odd.  EDIT and I know $row['id'] isn't null, since I'm echoing it and it's always a number.  So confused.

Comment: This would typically mean than `$row['id']` is not setup correctly/initialized or is not what you expect. You can test this with `echo var_export($row, TRUE);` to see what the value is in `$row['id']` before you pass it to the query.

Comment: Thanks.  I will continue looking into this and update when/if I find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`$todelete = $row["id"];`

`$query = "DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$todelete'";`

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a variable first

```
 $id=$response['id'];
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$id'");
```

if  'id' is an integer not need to keep in quotes. you can write like this

```
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID=$id");
```

Comment: I've actually tried this, no good.  I honestly have no clue why.  I'm looking at the other suggestions now... (but thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM default_ps_products WHERE ID='".$todelete."'");
```

or you can use this also

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM default_ps_products WHERE ID=$todelete");
```

it will work fine. hope you found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the correct value for $row['id']  and $result ?

Have you tried dumping $result and $row['id']?

Try

```
 var_dump($result);
```

If it gives you the correct array with the values you want. You can do:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 $todelete = $row["id"];
 mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$todelete'");
```

Or You might need to do this :

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array()){
           $todelete = $row["id"];
           mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID='$todelete'");


  }
```

Try doing var_dump() of $result, $row, $row['id'] etc on each steps to DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this-

```
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID=' " .$response['id']. " ' ");
```

or rather just use this

```
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM balloons WHERE ID=' " .$row['id']. " ' ");
```

Also, I hope you checked if you are are getting the correct result into row['id']